# Custom Post Type & Taxonomies - Rewrite

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I use Custom Post Type UI plugin to create new post types and taxonomies.

I created post type `cpt_recipes`

```
"has_archive" => "recipes",
"rewrite" => [ "slug" => "recipe", "with_front" => true ],
```

First taxonomy `cpt_recipes_cat`

```
"hierarchical" => true,
"rewrite" => [ 'slug' => 'recipes/category', 'with_front' => true,  'hierarchical' => true, ],
```

Second taxonomy `cpt_recipes_ingredient`

```
"hierarchical" => true,
"rewrite" => [ 'slug' => 'recipes/ingredient', 'with_front' => true,  'hierarchical' => true, ],
```

Now how to remove `/category` and `/ingredient` from the taxonomy archive url and make it work?

Or how to remove only `/category` from the first taxonomy archive url and make it work?

Comment: Not clear what is not working? What are you trying to achieve? Need more detials & possibly code.

Comment: I want to remove taxonomy slug from single term archive url. I want to eg. `cpt_recipes_cat` term archive url to look like /recipes/category-name/ and for `cpt_recipes_ingredient` term archive url /recipes/ingredient-name/. At now when I remove from rewrite rule /category or /ingredient I gets Error 404 at term archive.

Comment: Please look at admin panel settings, at link structure. I think you should handle it there